# Notepad++ Search within search results

Tags: full-text-search, notepad++

Simple question, is it possible to search within search results in notepad++ (excluding copying & pasting the search results panel text into a searchable file)? There seems to be surprisingly little information about this.

If not, any links to relevant regex solutions/tutorials that accomplish the equivalent through use of 'and/or' logic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure when this feature was introduced but you can right click the Search text and click "Find in these found results..."

[image]